# A Load/Stress test gets down my ASP.net MVC 4 in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, iis-7.5, stress-testing

I have a web site in a production server with its own application pool.
The web server is IIS7 and the tech is ASP.net MVC4. SQL Server Express 2012 for the database queries.
I have made a load/stress test o know the response times.
The tool i have used is:
http://loadimpact.com/

My surprise comes when it gets my site down. The app pool has some warnings and after that the app pool has stopped, so it shows an error showing the service is down.

If i request my site though the browser everything is fine and goes fast. I think my app pool is bad configurated (it is the default conf) and dont support several clients requesting at the same time.

How could i detect the problem and fix it?

Comment: You should not be doing stress/load tests in your production environment. A staging environment, within the same server or (preferably) in a different server with the same config should be used instead. What kind of error do you get? ASP.NET errors? LoadImpact errors?

Comment: You are right but we dont have an staging environment nowadays. I have not tried the stress test again, but we are not having problems with the server so i gived up. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, that's what really matters. I am in a phase that might need to prepare and execute some load/stress tests sson. I will see what I will use for them...